# All errors result in URLconf circular import

Tags: python, django

Any error in my django app results in:

```
The included URLconf 'appname.urls' does not appear to have any 
patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue 
is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I realized when stepping through in pdb that any error that occurs in my app results in the URLconf error. The pdb will show the error that actually occurred, but if I continue the console will just print the URLconf error shown above. If I go and fix the error pdb showed such as the SyntaxError I resolved then everything works fine. It seems like any error I have just results in the URLconf error shown above and I am not sure how to resolve it so that I can see that actual error without going through pdb.

Update:
I was using Python 3.5.2, upgrading to the latest Python 3.6.9 has fixed the error.

Comment: Please, share both urls files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Python 3.5.2 and after some more searching it looks like it was a Python problem. Upgrading to Python 3.6.9 solved the issue.